# Does this condition correct for the defined function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

This is question should be  completely obvious but I just wanted to make sure no extra assumption is needed. Let $h\colon (2,3)\to\Bbb R$ be a function and define $f(x)=h(x)$ for every $x\in(2,3)$ and $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in\Bbb R\setminus(2,3).$

Let $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $a<b$ such that $f(a)<f(b).$ I am supposed to show that there are $c<d$ between $a$ and $b$ and in $(2,3).$ I think, this is true without  more conditions about $f.$ Indeed, without loss of generality, assume $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)>0$.Other cases can be done in the similar way. So, $b$ must be in (2,3), that is $a<2<b<3$. Then, there exist $c<d$ such that $$a<2<c<d<b<3.$$ I do not think no extra assumptions are needed for the existence of $c$ and $d$. Does that correct?

Comment: No extra assumptions are needed. The problem is equivalent to showing that if $a<b,\, a<3, \,2<b$ then $(a,b)$ has non-empty intersection with $(2,3)$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, Thank you  so much. How if we need to make sure $f(a)<f(c)<f(d)<f(b)$. What condition are needed to ensure that ? If the graph of $h$ is dense in $(2,3)\times\Bbb R$. This would do. But maybe is too much . what do you thing ?

Comment: $h$ does not matter. We know that since $f(a)<f(b)$ then $b$ cannot be less than $2$, and that $a$ cannot be greater than $3$. We are given that $a<b$. That is all the information we need to reach the conclusion.

Comment: Wait, I did not see any requirement that $f(a)<f(c)<f(d)$, only that $c<d$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, Let be make clear. I am done with my question in OP. I am consider another case. If $f(a)<f(b)$ then we ensured that there exist $c<d$ such that $a<2<c<d<3$. So, now I need to see if I want to ensure that extra condition for the values of $c$ and $d$ such that $f (a)<f(2)<f(c)<f(d)<f(b)$. If I assume the graph of $h$ is dense in $(2,3)\times \Bbb R$ This will do. But the density is too strong . Do you other condition that can ensure that ?

Comment: Any positive increasing function $h$ on $(2,3)$ should satisfy the condition. It would also be the case that $b$ must be in $(2,3)$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, Thank you very much. Can this be achieved by assume $0$ is cluster point of $h$  at the endpoint.